# comparing each sequence created in the loop to the previous

Tags: python

I have created a function in python which randomly generates nucleotide sequence:

```
import random
selection60 = {"A":20, "T":20, "G":30, "C":30}
sseq60=[]
for k in selection60:
    sseq60 = sseq60 + [k] * int(selection60[k])
    random.shuffle(sseq60)
for i in range(100):
            random.shuffle(sseq60)
def generateSequence(self, length):
    length = int(length)
    sequence = ""
    while len(sequence) < length:
        sequence="".join(random.sample(self, length))
    return sequence[:length]
```

Now, I would like to check that while I apply this function, if a newly created sequence has a similarity of > 10% to the previous sequences, the sequence is eliminated and a new one is created:
I wrote something like this:

```
    lst60=[]
    newSeq=[]
    for i in range(5):
        while max_identity < 10:
            newSeq=generateSequence(sseq60,100)
            identity[i] = [newSeq[i] == newSeq[i] for i in range(len(newSeq[i]))]
max_identity[I]=100*sum(identity[i]/length(identity[i])
                lst60.append(newSeq)
                print(len(lst60))
```

However, it seems I get an empty list

Comment: Remember that, when you're creating a new list, `lst60[-1]` always contains the last element.  Note that your 6th line has the condition `newSeq[i] == newSeq[i]`, which will always be true.

Comment: Couple of comments. 1. What is `identity`? Is it a list or string or an integer? Is it greater than 10 initially? 2. `newSeq[i] == newSeq[i]` This will always be true.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I noticed it, that's why I used append(), Yes, I think newSeq[i] == newSeq[i] is not the proper way to write it, how do I write that a newly created sequence is compared the previous sequences in the loop?

Comment: @DeepakGouda identity is a max value that should be generating while comparing each sequence to the previous one in the loop

Comment: basically in the loop 5 sequences are created with that function, I want sequence 2 to be compared to sequence 1 and sequence 3 compared to sequence 1 and 2 and so on till sequence 5 which is compared to 1,2,3,4

Comment: if there is an identity of matching > 10 it will be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a nested for loop if you want to compare `i`th sequence with `j`th sequence for all 1 <= j < i.

Further, I created a separate `getSimilarity` function for easier code readability. Pass it an old and new sequence to get the similarity.

```py
def getSimilarity(old_seq, new_seq):
    similarity = [old_seq[i] == new_seq[i] for i in range(len(new_seq))]
    return 100*sum(similarity)/len(similarity)

lst60=[generateSequence(sseq60,100)]
for i in range(1,5):
    newSeq = ""
    max_identity = 0
    while True:
        newSeq = generateSequence(sseq60,100)
        for j in range(0,i):
            max_identity = max(max_identity, getSimilarity(lst60[j], newSeq))
        if max_identity < 10:
            break
    lst60.append(newSeq)
    print(len(lst60))
```

Comment: PS : The function `getSimilarity` works under the assumption that both the sequences are of same length.

Comment: yes, that is what I had in mind as well, to have a new function which can make the comparison, thank you

Comment: hi, should not be  getSimilarity(newSeq[I], newSeq[j]) ?

Comment: also, the loop seems stuck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232387/discussion-between-deepak-gouda-and-paolo-lorenzini).